# How to output results to console instead .txt - X12 Parser?

Tags: c#, console, edi, x12

I am testing this EDI standard: X12 Parser ([link](http://x12parser.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20flat%20file%20from%20the%20X12%20xml%20using%20XSLT%20and%20XslCompiledTransform)), now example in link have as result.txt. The code that does this is:

```
using OopFactory.X12.Parsing;
using OopFactory.X12.Parsing.Model;

namespace MyX12.Edi835Parser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stream transformStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyX12.Edi835Parser.X12-835-To-CSV.xslt");
            Stream inputStream = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            Stream outputFile = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

            X12Parser parser = new X12Parser();
            Interchange interchange = parser.Parse(inputStream);
            string xml = interchange.Serialize();

            var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            transform.Load(XmlReader.Create(transformStream));

            transform.Transform(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)), new XsltArgumentList(), outputFile);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code has: Stream outputFile = new FileStream(args[1](http://x12parser.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20flat%20file%20from%20the%20X12%20xml%20using%20XSLT%20and%20XslCompiledTransform) ... where args[1](http://x12parser.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20flat%20file%20from%20the%20X12%20xml%20using%20XSLT%20and%20XslCompiledTransform) is in project properties / Debug set as Sample-Output.txt, which is the name of file that would be created.

Now, I want to have the result instead as Sample-Output.txt, in my console, something like this:

```
Stream outputFile = Console.Write();
```

Really thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.OpenStandardOutput()` acquires the standard output stream.

Try replacing

```
Stream outputFile = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

with

```
Stream outputFile = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
```